# In python 2.6.6, why is integer -1 is greater than 0

Tags: python

I am baffled as to why -1 is greater than 0.
This my test program

```
> cat logtest.py
def myfunc():
    if -1 > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

if myfunc():
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
> python -V
Python 2.6.6
> python logtest.py
True
```

If I do this in the interpreter, I get a different result:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Apr 11 2011, 15:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if -1 > 0:
...  print "Whoa!"
... else:
...  print "unWhoa!"
...
unWhoa!
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it prints `True` it means that -1 > 0 is wrong! Check your code again, you return `True` in the `else` block. Everything is working correctly.

Comment: Why are you not just returning `-1 > 0` here? That is *already a boolean value*. That way you don't mix up your booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `False` when `-1 > 0` is True, and vice versa:

```
 >>> if -1 > 0:
...     print 'True, the universe is indeed upside down!'
... else:
...     print 'False, order has been restored'
... 
False, order has been restored
```

but you do this:

```
if -1 > 0:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

so you are basically doing this:

```
>>> not -1 > 0
True
```

You **inverted** the test outcome, return `False` when the test is true, `True` when the test outcome is false, but your console test doesn't match that logic. There you only looked at the test outcome itself.

Your error stems from explicitly returning boolean values after executing an expression that *already* produces a boolean. It is very easy to get that wrong, and you *don't need to do this*. Just return the expression **itself**:

```
def myfunc():
    return -1 > 0

print myfunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly. You just seemed to have misinterpreted the logic. `-1 > 0` evaluates to `False`, so we expect to enter in the `else` block if provided.

```
if -1 > 0:
    print "-1 IS greater than 0"
else:
    print "-1 IS NOT greater than 0"

# -1 IS NOT greater than 0
```

Try this simpler example:

```
print -1 > 0
# False
```

Comment: Thanks to other helpers also. I marked up the explanation that was the most explicit.